# jQuery/Javascript - select last word in physical line of paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure this is possible but I wondered if there is a way of targeting the last word in a line of text within a paragraph. Note that I'm not looking for the last word in the paragraph but the last word in a line of said paragraph.

I haven't the faintest idea of how to start with this so haven't got an attempt formulated.

Thanks for any help you can offer!
Mark

Comment: Can you give us an example to start from? do you need to work with strings or DOM elements?

Comment: I have no example because I don't know how to construct the logic. I want to target the last word on each line of a <p> element, let's call it '#thisparagraph' for the sake of understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a JS library, [jsLineWrapDetector](https://github.com/xdamman/js-line-wrap-detector), which can retrieve the lines from the text wrapped by DOM element.

```js
var p = $("p")[0];
var lines = lineWrapDetector.getLines(p);
lines.forEach(function(line) {
  var lastword = line.split(" ").pop();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy but I think this is for the last word in the paragraph, if I'm not mistaken? I'm hoping for the last word of each line within that paragraph as it appears on the page.

Comment: You are right. I misread your question. Let me see if I can correct it. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkHolland May I know what **physical line** means? Are there any line break or just the lines wrapped by browser?

Comment: just the lines wrapped by the browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text of p tag, split them on occurrence of space to create the array of word. then target the last element in returned array. Like this:

```
var wordarray = $('p').text().split(" ");
return wordarray [wordarray.length - 1];
```

Comment: +1 but this will get the last paragraph's last word. You need to specify which `p` you want to extract the last word from.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: i agree. but op have not shared the markup which would have helped to use most relevant selector.

Comment: Thank you Milind. As I mentioned I have no attempt at the code yet because I don't know what the logic is. The selector itself isn't an issue as I can do that. However, your solution above is for the last word in the paragraph, if I'm not mistaken? I'm looking for the last word in a line of a paragraph, so for example, getting the last word on each line of this paragraph I'm writing. Do you happen to know how I might do that?

Comment: @MarkHolland: sure we can. please create a fiddle with p tag and its content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
function getLastWord(paragraph, line) {
  return paragraph.split("\n")[line].split(" ").pop();
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ssxwccnn/)

Comment: Thank you Jax. Reading the above it looks like this might do what I'm looking for! I may be being stupid here (probably) but I get the following error using your exact code (perhaps I need to change a couple of parameters to reflect my situation?) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @MarkHolland Event if you find your solution, you need to pass in first parameter `$("id_paragrpah").text()` or modify my function by `return paragraph.text()....` and pass only `$("id_paragraph")` in first parameter. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will find the last word of each line (of a p tag), and throw all of them in the console.  `words[i - 1]`, or `breakWord` is the last word of each line. Hopefully, this helps.

```
var breakWord
var p = $('p');

p.each(function () {
    var current = $(this);
    var text = current.text();

    var words = text.split(' ');

    current.text(words[0]);
    var height = current.height();

    for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]);

        if (current.height() > height) {
            height = current.height();
            breakWord = words[i - 1];
            console.log(breakWord);
        }
    }

    console.log(current);
});
```

This code will split the whole paragraph up into single words, put them in an array (`words`), and then check for line breaks. When a line break is found, it returns the last word of the line.